# What word can be used to describe someone you're following?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, social-media, er-ee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s a good word for a person that’s being followed?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23518/whats-a-good-word-for-a-person-thats-being-followed)

For example, a Twitter user can have many *followers*. Twitter refers to the users that another user is following as *following*, more in a verbal sense of the word.

> @johndoe is following 283 users

What one word could be used as a noun to label those whom one is following? I thought of *followee* and a coworker came across *guide*, of which I’m not sure how it works.

Comment: *Guide* only makes sense if you mean literally following, as in going where they tell you to go. In this context, "following" means you are keeping track of where they go -- they are not leading you but informing you. So *guide* doesn't really work.

Comment: Aha! Now I get it...

Comment: "People I stalk"?

Comment: @VictorStanciu Hmmm, might be viable... However, not only am I seeking a one word answer, but I'd like to keep my users from feeling uneasy about using our site :)

Comment: The title made me think *quarry* or *prey*, but then I saw that the question was about "following" in the Twitter sense, and I no longer find those very appropriate. :-P

Comment: Those who tweet are "birds"! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- @johndoe is following 283 [publishers](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/publisher), [syndicators](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/syndicator), or [sources](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/source).
- @johndoe is following 283 [feeds](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/feeds), [streams](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stream) or [subscriptions](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subscription).

Comment: "Publishers", "Syndicators", "Sources" going on whiteboard. "Feeds" and "Subscriptions" are already referring to something else

Answer (score 2):

Twitter's under-the-hood term for a [user you follow is *friend*](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/friends/ids). The URL https://twitter.com/friends is also an alias of https://twitter.com/following.

As a general term, I'd suggest *leader* or *interest*.

Comment: Yes. "Friend" is a little bit informal for what I'm going for. Good suggestion, though.

Comment: "Interest" is now on the whiteboard

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion for someone you follow might be [*doyen*](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/Doyen):

> **doy·en**   [doi-en, doi-uhn; Fr. dwa-yan]   *noun*, plural doy·ens
>    [doi-enz, doi-enz; Fr. dwa-yan] 
>   The most respected or prominent person in a particular field

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

- Object, subject, focus, focal point
- Polestar, lodestar, cynosure
- Center, hub, navel, omphalos