# Synonym for observee

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a synonym for observee, i.e. something that is observed. The word observee doesn't seem be used much, so I would like to have a more common word if it exists.

I need to use it in a very abstract sense, so my example sentence doesn't get more concrete than this: "The observer watched the observee very closely."

Comment: The *observed*.

Comment: _subject_ might work

Comment: *Target*, *Object (of observation)*. You need to include some context. There could be many words including *person of interest*.

Comment: @sumelic single word. *Subject* seems to be the most fitting until now.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23518/whats-a-good-word-for-a-person-thats-being-followed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to reuse some terminology from software world here.

There is a standard software design pattern called [Observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) and its terminology may help. Quoting [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern):

> The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which **an object,
>   called the subject**, maintains a list of its dependents, called
>   observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes,
>   usually by calling one of their methods.

Also there is a [Observable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) interface which may be implemented by observable objects. Quoting its description:

> An **observable object** can have one or more observers.

[I know **subject** was a previous answer but I think this was too long as a comment.]

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/observable) gives observable as a noun. Although it means something which can be observable, in many contexts that is equivalent to something which is observed (e.g. if you're talking about the observer-observable relationship in the abstract).

Answer (score 1):

***Videndum*** is defined as "the thing which is to be seen" ([here](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/videndum)).

***Observandum*** is defined as "a thing to be observed" ([here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/observandum)).

If you want to stick to the strict Latin and need "the thing observed," or "the object of the observation," you might go with @TimLymington's suggestion in the comments below of ***observatum***.

They are somewhat archaic but would work well in a technical or academic setting.

Comment: There is an important distinction between ' the thing observed' and ' the thing to be observed'. If you really want this, it would have to be *observatum*

Comment: @TimLymington is right. I made an edit to include his suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I think the suggestion of *subject* that was given to you in a comment is probably best, but you could also go with ***specimen.***