# Noun for person being observed

Tags: nouns

I know that the person being interviewed is interviewee, but I cannot find the equivalent for the person being observed! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about the observed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synonym for observee](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/303681/synonym-for-observee)

Comment: The following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: Please give the context. Who is observing whom? A spy observing another agent? An assasin observing a mark? A psychologist observing an experimental subject?   A doctor observing a patient?

Answer (score 2):

Wiktionary cites ***[observee](http://www.yourdictionary.com/observee):***, but it appears to be used mainly in scientific contexts:

Noun
(plural observees)

> - One who is observed.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=observee&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cobservee%3B%2Cc0): "observee"

> - I do not know the student whom I came to observe, at this point the teacher will assist me by laying her hand casually ***on the observee's shoulder*** as she ends her.... From  [Ready-to-Use Information & Materials for Assessing Specific Learning Disabilitis](https://books.google.it/books?id=YchKAAAAYAAJ&q=%22observee%22&dq=%22observee%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6h5PLoevMAhXEWxQKHamRBrQQ6AEITDAH)

...

> - Thus, on days and at times selected by the observee, ***two observers show up at the observee' s work site*** and use a standard behavioral checklist to conduct a systematic 30-minute observation session, followed by interactive feedback... From [Safety, Health, and Asset Protection](https://books.google.it/books?id=JghPAAAAMAAJ&q=%22observee%22&dq=%22observee%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9w5GmouvMAhVGWhQKHfRoAxgQ6AEIUzAI)

Answer (score 0):

Subject. Wiktionary says

> A human, animal or an inanimate object that is being examined, treated, analysed, etc